# Arangodb using Java API: when a graph is created do all Edges need to be defined already?

Tags: arangodb

As far as I can tell, you must specify the edge definitions at creation time and there does not seem to be a method for adding an edge definition later. But I also see examples written in Javascript (I think) where edge definitions can be added later. Am I right about this Java limitation and does that suggest that Javascript might be a better choice for programming language to interact with ArangoDB?

EDIT: Could the edgeDefinitions Collection be added to after the graph is created?

EDIT: Seems to me that since the Java API is making REST calls, adding to the Collection later would not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add an edge definition to an existing graph by using the method `addEdgeDefinition` of the [ArangoDB-Java-Driver](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver).

An example is listed in the [Java Driver documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Drivers/Java/Reference/Graph/EdgeCollection.html#arangographaddedgedefinition.).

Similar it is possible to replace/remove an edge definition by`replaceEdgeDefinition`/`removeEdgeDefinition`.

Comment: Could it be I am confusing graph entity with graph handler?